# How do I keep this time output updating every second?

Tags: java, android

```
public void CentralTime()
{

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM d, yyyy, h:mm:ss a");
    TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(utc);
    Date now = gc.getTime();
    centralTimeJava = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.centralTime);
    centralTimeJava.setText(format.format(now));




}
```

This is the method I call to output. How would I get it so that the seconds keep updating within the app. Currently it would only output the time at the moment the method was called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a handler to repeat the task on specify timing.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable handlerTask = new Runnable()
{
  @Override 
  public void run() { 

    // do something. update text view.  
    handler.postDelayed(handlerTask, 1000);  // 1000 ms = 1 second

  }
};
handlerTask.run();
```

If you want to stop the handler, do this:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(handlerTask);
```